# Changing redirect path in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function submitStore ( Request $r )
    {
$site->url = $uri;
}
```

```
        // redirect to the new listing
        return redirect()->route( 'home' );
```

I want to redirect it to `https://example.com/$uri` instead of redirecting to `'home'` How can I do this? Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-external-domains

gives you

```php
return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');
```